# Trigger not saving due to incorrect method signature

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

[image]Everything is perfect . Just a short code with few lines . But still the trigger is not saving . It works in other ORGs but not in my Developer Edition ORG . Please help me with it.

```
Task Trigger:

trigger taskTrigger on Task (before insert, after insert, after update, before update, before delete, after delete) {
    
   TaskHandler.checkOwner(Trigger.old);
   
}

Task Handler:

public class TaskHandler {
   
   public static void checkOwner(List<Task> triggeredTaskRecord){
      
       System.debug('This is a Task trigger');
       
   }
   
}
```

I even tried with sharing , tried non static methods but still the problem exists . Don't know what to do

Comment: You probably have some other class in there that you are shadowing - try changing the classname to TaskHandler1 just to check.

Comment: I have tried The class name was " TaskTriggerHandler " before I tried changing it to TaskHandler but still that didn't work .  Another thing is I tried to send a empty list of task and it worked . Sending the Trigger.new failed . I don't know why

Comment: N.B. `Trigger.old` is undefined in `before insert` and `after insert` context

Comment: Actually I tried using all the context variables . The main task was using isBefore and isDelete . But still Trigger.old is not available there . I don't know what's the problem there. And also the problem is with saving the class Even though your solution is considered it should raise runtime errors . Here the class is not even compiled